# Leaving Stack Exchange - my reasons

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

As you can tell from my username, I support [Monica's fight against what SE did to her](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/se-has-removed-a-moderator). The actions taken by those in charge at SE have left a very bitter taste in my mouth, and while I have not left Writing, my visits have all but evaporated. I used to have Writing open in a tab on my browser all day, every day. Now I only visit once a week or less, and then only for a few minutes. The attacks against Monica, the resulting accusations and general negativity, and the subsequent leaving by many moderators and downturn in site quality have all contributed to this lack of activity.

It has now become increasingly clear to me that:

1. There is nothing we can do to rectify the situation, because we have too little power to do anything, and SE does not care.
2. Because SE does not care (and in fact probably thinks there is no problem, or that things will blow over), they will not do anything to fix the issue.

This means that any action taken on our part is purely for our benefit, or the benefit of the community.

I have no desire to hurt the community by leaving, but the fact is that I have (unofficially) already left. As I said, my activity has taken a serious downturn, and I feel no inclination to ask or answer any questions. That is why it is my belief that I should find a new group of writers, where I can help the community with a good conscience, and not one constantly reminding me that I am helping (in however small a way) SE to stay alive.

This doesn't mean I want SE to die. The platform is excellent, and the community is (from what I've seen) comprised of some of the most open-minded and helpful people on the internet. Those in charge at SE, and those who back what they did to Monica, need to be gracious enough to own up to what they did, apologize, and then step down if Monica and the community request it.

That will never happen (both because they are too far down the rabbit hole now, and also because it is their company, and they can technically do whatever they want with it).

Those in charge have opted to blind themselves with current political issues, and now are incapable of realizing (or refuse to do so, which is even worse if true) that they are using that blindness to champion the very cause they preach against: defaming and harming a person who does not agree with them.

To sum up:

- My activity has plummeted due to a general feeling of negativity towards SE as a whole.
- While I have no wish to harm the community by leaving, I feel I could be of more use elsewhere, where I will feel inclined to contribute.
- I cannot feel comfortable contributing to a site owned and run by people who practice mental and emotional harm against those who disagree with them, and then offer no attempt to mitigate that harm.

Due to these reasons, I am now looking for an alternative to Writing SE, a place where general questions about Writing can be penned and answered, and opinions discussed freely.

I have not yet been able to find such a place, but will continue searching. If anyone else is of the same mind and has already found such an alternative, I would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

EDIT: While not a permanent solution, I have decided to create a Discord server for those of us who have left Writers. It will allow us to ask and answer questions, while keeping everyone in the loop as we look for a more permanent solution. If you are interested in joining, the link is in my profile.

FURTHER EDIT: ArtofCode has been gracious enough to allow us access to [what I feel could be a permanent solution](https://qpixel.artofcode.co.uk/questions/39219). The website will obviously need to be moved off of his private server at some point if we go with it, but I encourage everyone to go there, make an account, claim your content, and start testing it out.

Comment: It's been an honour and a pleasure. I'm in the same boat - came back after a break, nothing has changed. I'm out.

Comment: I wish we had a place we could all gather to talk.  I hate that we're all saying goodbye to the community we all built together.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Maybe we could create a Writing discord? Or something similar?

Comment: Please don't go!  Back off as much as you need to (I've done the same) but keep the account.  If there is an alt community, we want you and others to have a way to know about it.

Comment: @CynsaysmakeMonicawhole I have no reason or desire to delete my account. And I will continue to check in sporadically, as I've been doing. This is basically just a formalization of where my activity was already at.

Comment: You voiced what probably many of us regulars feel. I am leaving this comment so that someone who comes across such a new place to gather may notify me, too. I am keeping my account because it means less ads on some of the sites that I need to visit, but I basically stopped contributing when all of this started.

Comment: So folks, us mods have been talking about where to host chat and haven't found the perfect place but Thomas has set up a chat room and we're gonna go for it.  Please join.  I'm super new to Discord and don't understand its features yet, so I find it annoying, but for a basic chatroom that isn't SE, it's good enough.  Hope to see you all there.

Comment: @SecSE-clearMonica'sname Notifying you that we have created such a place where we can continue. Please join the site, as detailed in the link in my OP under 'further edit', and also feel free to join the discord, linked in my profile.

Comment: I think you or somebody should make those links into an answer so they're more visible.  Or if that doesn't fit this Q&A, maybe create a separate one to draw more attention.

Comment: I'd suggest updating the post to include links to relevant posts regarding what happened with Monica. I hardly read Meta at all, and had to dig around to find out what was going on. Much respect to all of you, sorry to see things turn out this way.

Comment: @Craig https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/se-has-removed-a-moderator?rq=1 looks like the main thread for Writing, was featured for a month but has since fallen down the list.  Unfortunately, Meta doesn't support suggested edits so someone with rep would have to edit it in.

Comment: @Troyen thanks, added it in.

Comment: That new alternative site does not run on stolen code, does it? With how similar it looks it hardly could have been built from the ground up?

Comment: @WeckarE. there is no stolen code.  This was a side project from a couple years ago that was dusted off and updated (and is being updated). For more information see [this meta post there](https://writing.codidact.com/questions/39219).

Comment: There's been some recent development: [Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio)

Comment: and that "agreement" contains no actual apology, nor has Monica been reinstated. She is *invited* to *apply* for reinstatement, which process she has already stated is flawed, and she will not endure it. Nothing has changed. I am in agreement with many people here: I'm just done with Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 9):

In sadness, I am also leaving.  I [said more on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342950/162102).

I've added contact information to my profile, and I've posted some
[information about my future plans](https://www.cellio.org/stack.html).  I won't be deleting my accounts.

The strength of a community is in its people.  I hope our community will stay connected wherever our path takes us.

Comment: I received a suggestion to post a new question: https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2301/1993